# How to export an Android Native Library as an .aar?

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I'm a little confused by this. I added a new library module to my project in Android studio from File->new->new module.  Then I selected "Android Native Library". This gave me a new library module that is similar to how you get a Java and c++ build setup when you are making a mixed application. In other words there are some java files in there for JNI along with the c++ files. I added this lib as a dependency for my project and everything works.

[image]

Now I want to export this as an AAR and I can't figure out how. I tried generating apks, generating signed apks, but all it ever outputs is my main application apk.  No AAR is created that I can find. I assume I'm missing a step?

My library's gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    minSdk 28
    targetSdk 31

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        version "3.18.1"
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```